# Instantiated optional variable shows as nil in Xcode debugger

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, xcode11, swift5

Since I upgraded to Xcode 11 and Swift 5.1 I've encountered a strange issue -- after an optional variable is instantiated, it can still show as up nil in the Xcode debugger!

I have an optional class variable called `booking`:

```
var booking: Booking?
```

It's of type `Booking`:

```
public struct Booking: Codable {
    var id: Int?
    var start_time: Date?
    var payment_currency: String = "USD"
    var payment_amount: Int?
}
```

When I'm stepping through the code, I can see `booking` before it's allocated... It's nil, great:

[image]

Then after it's allocated... What, still nil??:

[image]

I wondered if it was being treated like a lazy variable somehow.  But it's not really nil, because it can be accessed:

[image]

After searching for a while, I wondered if my build schema in Xcode didn't have its "Debug executable" flag set.  But it does.  I even cleaned and rebuilt the project with the flag off and on to be sure.

[image]

Whether I view `booking` in the Variables View or enter `p booking` in the Console View, it shows up as nil.

What's going on here?  I need the predictability of debugging I had before this upgrade.

**UPDATE**

I distilled a simple way to reproduce the issue.  First, create an empty single-view project and add this to the top of AppDelegate.swift:

```
public struct Booking: Codable {
    var start_time: Date?
    var payment_currency: String = "USD"
}
```

Then add these lines to the application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) func:

```
booking = Booking()
print("booking.payment_currency = \(booking?.payment_currency ?? "NULL")")
```

Set a breakpoint as before and when running, notice that the debugger shows booking as nil even after being assigned, as in my original case.

*Then comment out* the `start_time` variable, re-run, and notice that now the debugger shows `booking` having a value after being assigned, as one would expect.

So it seems that Date variables, optional or not, in a struct like this make debugging confusing.  Specifically Date variables -- change the variable to other types like Int, Int?, String, String?... and there's no issue.

Unless I'm missing something very basic, this seems like a bug in the Xcode debugger to me.  If so, would the best way to report it be at https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/?

Comment: Can you provide instructions for reproducing this issue? If so it could be a good bug report to Apple.

Comment: I think that's my next step tomorrow, trying to distill it down into a very small project.  I'm hoping somebody else has encountered this though, and that there's a simple solution or something else I don't know.

Comment: I can't tell without reproducing, but your description and screen shots just scream "bug" at me. :)

Comment: Have you tried the usual go-to trouble shooting steps? In order of increasing nuisance: restarting Xcode, clean build, clearing derived data.

Comment: I did all of those things, @Alexander.  Alas, no luck.

Comment: @matt I was able to reproduce it.  Please see the UPDATE above.

Comment: The bug is easily reproducible. Better send a bug report as soon as possible.

Comment: Great work, well done!

Comment: Struggled with this for hours. Created test cases, etc., until finding this post. It's still an issue but the one way around it is to use NSDate instead of Date. The issue is absolutely the date even if it is not an optional.

Comment: It can be revealed by mapping the object to obj-c, e.g. `latestOpenReport?.controlPackagesValidTo as NSDate`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It appears I've found a bug in Xcode 11.  It's easily reproducible as outlined in the **UPDATE** above.  I've filed the bug with Apple.

I'm still looking for a workaround now, since I use quite a few structs containing Date variables.  If anybody can find one, please comment below.

Comment: Probably the same bug as this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58155061/convert-string-to-url-why-is-resulting-variable-nil In that one, the situation is completely different, but again we have a `nil` shown in the debugger when in fact the thing is not `nil` at all.

Comment: Just found the same bug.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58636312/decoder-decode-setting-valid-iso8601-date-as-nil/58653084#58653084 ...  I was debugging and spent hours trying to re-work the code.  I had too much trust in what the debugger was telling me.  It wasn't nil at all... Ughhhh

Comment: @user1060500 Annoying isn't it?  I'd encourage you to report it to Apple, and track https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-11593, which is where the bug report matt submitted below seems to have landed.

Comment: These reported bugs show status as resolved, but I'm on Version 11.2.1 (11B500) and still experiencing the same bug, but even worse

Comment: As of now this one still is open: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-11593.  Not sure when any of this will roll into Xcode anyway.  Seems we might just have to keep reporting this to Apple directly with each release.  I find it's still an impediment to development.

Comment: Still facing this issue in XCode 12

Answer (score 14):

The cause of the bug is not that `var start_time: Date?` is present or absent, but that Date is a Swift Foundation overlay. If you remove the Codable conformance and make `start_time` an `NSDate?`, everything is fine. So clearly LLDB gets confused by Swift overlay types like `Date?`.

In [this linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58155061/convert-string-to-url-why-is-resulting-variable-nil), we see the same issue with `URL?`. If we change it to `NSURL?` everything is fine.

I'm not saying that that's a viable workaround! You want and need to use Swift types. I'm just saying that this is what is messing up LLDB. You can include that info when you report the bug.

**This bug is slated to be fixed in Xcode 12.5.**

Comment: You might want to link your bug report with mine. We need them to fix this!

Comment: Amen, will do! One small note -- I found it doesn't have to be optionals.

Comment: Oh no! I thought I'd tested so brilliantly. :(

Comment: Ha! No, you did. Thanks for posting the big there too. They’ll sort it out.

Comment: I am still seeing this problem in XCode 11.1 and almost the end of October.  I can do a po and it it works.

Comment: XCode11.2.1, the bug still exist, which cost my whole day ...

Comment: Still exists in XCode 11.3.1.

Comment: Still seeing this in XCode 11.6 urgh!

Comment: @KeithL Yes, there has been some useful talk about the problem on the bugs.swift.org forum, but we're not any closer to the heart of the matter.

Comment: The po LLDB command does not suffer with this problem, you should us it instead of print