# Date shows nil when debugging but date string has a value, is this some kind of bug in Xcode or expected behavior

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, date, debugging

I'm assigning `date` to a variable by `adding days` to current date and get the `string` from that date like below.

```
let today = Date()
let duedate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: due, to: today)

let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
dateformatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy"
duedateString = dateformatter.string(from: duedate!)
```

This works fine. but when I debug, I'm getting following issue

[image]
[image]
 [image]

hope this shouldn't be the expected behavior. anyone has an idea or experienced with this and anyone knows the reason for this.

Comment: [Here is a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58108824/instantiated-optional-variable-shows-as-nil-in-xcode-debugger). Maybe they are caused by the same bug in Xcode?

Comment: I tested your code and 'duedate' isn't nil for me.

Comment: What version of Xcode?