# Convert String to URL (Why is resulting variable nil)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, url, null

I'm trying to create an URL variable from a string value. I don't understand why the resulting URL is nil

I have set up a new Xcode macOS project, placed a simple button on the View, created an action for that button and implemented the following code. The resulting url is nil.

I tried the same in Swift playground and there it worked...

```swift
    @IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        let urlAsString = "http://www.google.de/"
        let url = URL(string: urlAsString)

        if url != nil {
            // Do work...
        }
    }
```

urlAsString is "http://www.google.de/" but
url is nil

[debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUATp.png)

Comment: @Sh_Khan does not for me. Check my edited post. I have attached a screenshot from the debugger

Comment: Change “do work” comment to print statement `print("it worked")`. Run the app, no breakpoint. Does it print?

Comment: @matt Yes, it does print "it worked". Seems to only display the wrong variable content?

Comment: Okay that's great! So either (1) you're using the debugger wrong, or (2) the debugger has a bug - it displays `nil` but the thing is _not_ nil. And (2) is perfectly possible! So either way, you have nothing to worry about; your code is working fine. The problem is just the debugger display of the value of `url`. Don't worry, be happy.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You've found a bug in the debugger!

**[This bug is slated to be fixed in Xcode 12.5.]**

It's easy to reproduce it:

[image]

We have paused at a breakpoint *inside* the condition. So obviously `url` is *not* `nil` or we wouldn't be here at all.

Another way to prove this is to `po url` in the console (see right-bottom of this screen shot):

[image]

Nevertheless, `url` shows as `nil` both in the tooltip and in the variables list. So the debugger is just lying to you: `url` is not nil. Don't worry, be happy. Your code is working fine.

**EDIT** The bug has something to do with the Swift Foundation overlay. If you change the declaration of `url` to this:

```
let url = NSURL(string: urlAsString)
```

...then everything works as expected.

And see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/58156592/341994

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. As an Swift novice I would have never thought about finding a bug in Xcode :-)

Comment: "Don't worry?". This bug has high potential for causing lots of errors and hours of wasted time :/. Thanks @matt for showing how to easily reproduce it, so I can file another bug report.

Comment: I've just started to learn Swift and was confused A LOT, spent 2 hours before finding this answer :(

Comment: Man!!!!! I have stared at screen for 4 hrs, poking some code that actually works, switching between URL NSURL, all because of this debugger bug, Thanks @matt for this post :)