# Swift URL Object returning nil despite po command returning data

Tags: swift, url

I had some trouble creating a URL object, both from a string and using URLComponents.

[image of code w/ some debugging messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZqmD.png)

```
var components = URLComponents()
components.scheme = "https"
components.host = "apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
components.path = "/stock/v2/get-statistics"
components.queryItems = [
     URLQueryItem(name: "region", value: "US"),
     URLQueryItem(name: "symbol", value: "TVIX")
]
let url = components.url
```

```
let url = URL(string: "https://apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com/stock/v2/get-statistics?region=US&symbol=\(stockSymbol)")
```

[link to API documentation page](https://rapidapi.com/apidojo/api/yahoo-finance1?endpoint=apiendpoint_aeccfc9c-66eb-4f4a-abf5-c14d952e09f6)

However, when testing the code, the url Object returns nil, despite using the po command in the 11db xcode console and seeing it return data (though using the "p" and "v" commands gave nil).

Anyone know how to construct the URL to properly contain data?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code into a playground and it worked just fine. Is this the actual code you were testing?

Comment: I just had a look at your image. If url was nil the program would have crashed on line 38 where you force unwrap the url. Looks like an issue with your debugger.

Comment: Yes, this was the actual code I was testing, and I also found that running the code in a playground worked fine, which was very confusing to me. Since optionals are essentially enumerations with two cases, do you think that there could be an issue interpreting/unwrapping the optional?   Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: I think this is the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58155061/convert-string-to-url-why-is-resulting-variable-nil