# IKScannerDeviceViewDelegate never called

Tags: swift, macos, ikscannerdeviceview

Probably a dumb question but I cannot figure how make it work. When I press scan button in my `IKScannerDeviceView` scan works but its delegate never gets called.
I put a breakpoint on line

```
print("Did scan to: \(url.path)")
```

Scan file appears in selected folder without problems but it never stops on breakpoint.
Am I missing something?
Just for the sake of completeness I'm using Xcode 12.2 on macOS 11.0.1

Here is my code:

```
import Cocoa
import ImageCaptureCore
import Quartz

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var scannerView: IKScannerDeviceView!
    var deviceBrowser:ICDeviceBrowser!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.scannerView.delegate = self
        self.scannerView.mode = .advanced
        self.scannerView.transferMode = .fileBased

        self.deviceBrowser = ICDeviceBrowser()
        self.deviceBrowser.delegate = self
        self.deviceBrowser.browsedDeviceTypeMask = ICDeviceTypeMask(rawValue:
                                                                        ICDeviceLocationTypeMask.local.rawValue |
                                                                        ICDeviceLocationTypeMask.shared.rawValue |
                                                                        ICDeviceLocationTypeMask.bonjour.rawValue |
                                                                        ICDeviceLocationTypeMask.remote.rawValue |
                                                                        ICDeviceLocationTypeMask.bluetooth.rawValue |
                                                                        ICDeviceTypeMask.scanner.rawValue)!
        self.deviceBrowser.start()
    }
}

extension ViewController : IKScannerDeviceViewDelegate {
    func scannerDeviceView(_ scannerDeviceView: IKScannerDeviceView!, didScanTo url: URL!, error: Error!) {
        print("Did scan to: \(url.path)")
    }
}

extension ViewController: ICDeviceBrowserDelegate {
    func deviceBrowser(_ browser: ICDeviceBrowser, didAdd device: ICDevice, moreComing: Bool) {

        if (device.type.rawValue & ICDeviceTypeMask.scanner.rawValue) == ICDeviceType.scanner.rawValue {
            self.scannerView.scannerDevice = (device as! ICScannerDevice)
        }
    }

    func deviceBrowser(_ browser: ICDeviceBrowser, didRemove device: ICDevice, moreGoing: Bool) {
        device.requestCloseSession()
    }

    func didRemoveDevice(device: ICDevice) {
        device.requestCloseSession()
    }

    func device(device: ICDevice, didEncounterError error: NSError?) {
        print("Error")
        print(error?.description ?? "----")
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the lines of code under IKScannerDeviceView.

Comment: Uhm...I think I don't understand: which lines? This all my code

Comment: Have you tried the other methods of `IKScannerDeviceViewDelegate`?

Comment: @Willeke just tried adding delegate methods `scannerDeviceView(_ scannerDeviceView: IKScannerDeviceView!, didEncounterError error: Error!)` and `scannerDeviceView(_ scannerDeviceView: IKScannerDeviceView!, didScanTo data: ICScannerBandData!, scanInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]!, error: Error!)` with same result

Comment: Try [scannerDeviceView(_:didScanTo:fileData:error:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartz/ikscannerdeviceviewdelegate/1504462-scannerdeviceview)

Comment: This one seems to work but all parameters (url, data, error) are `nil `

Comment: Is `url` really `nil` or is Xcode showing `nil`? See [Convert String to URL (Why is resulting variable nil)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58155061/convert-string-to-url-why-is-resulting-variable-nil)

Comment: I was fooled by Xcode debugger showing nil. If I put `print(url.path)`it prints correct path. Sorry to not have tried this before. So it seems the only delegate method called is the one you suggested. Many thanks, if you put in a response I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the following methods are not called:

```
func scannerDeviceView(IKScannerDeviceView!, didScanTo: ICScannerBandData!, scanInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]!, error: Error!)
func scannerDeviceView(IKScannerDeviceView!, didScanTo: URL!, error: Error!)
```

Implement the following method instead:

```
func scannerDeviceView(IKScannerDeviceView!, didScanTo: URL!, fileData: Data!, error: Error!)
```