# Xcode 11, swift. Dateformatter always return nil

Tags: swift, date, xcode11, dateformatter

I have a problem with converting value from `String` to `Date` in Swift.

It always returns nil. What am I doing wrong?

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2019-05-03")
```

Here is what is happening in the debugger in Xcode

[image]

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile, please edit your question

Comment: Yeah, i updated description

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32408916/2303865

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update:

It would appear that it is a bug in Xcode. Trying your code in the `viewDidLoad` and setting a breakpoint causes the `lldb` description of the date to be `nil`, however it correctly prints the expected value out.

[image: lldb missing value]

You can see more about the bug at this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58108824/instantiated-optional-variable-shows-as-nil-in-xcode-debugger), thanks to OOPer for the link.

Currently this bug is still occurring in Xcode 11.2-beta

---

A couple of points

Use `.dateFormat` instead of `.format`

Use the correct quotation marks `"` instead of `”`, also you should remove the space from your date format string.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2019-05-03")
```

[image: Image showing above code working in Playgrounds]

Comment: Sorry, i wrote incorrect code in description. I always do as you sad and it is nil .

Comment: The above code compiles and is not nil l. So there must be something else that you are doing that is causing it to be nil.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvdJB.png I did the same. Can it be a bug in Xcode 11 ?

Comment: Yes, I would think that it is an error in Xcode. However it seems to be only with the debugger's description.

Comment: It's a known bug of Xcode 11. Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58108824/6541007).

Answer (score 0):

It does not have a `nil` value. Use `.dateFormat` instead of `.format` It's a simple as this:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2019-05-03")

// Optional(2019-05-02 23:00:00 +0000)
```

Comment: Sorry, i wrote incorrect code in description. I always do as you sad and it is nil .