# decoder.decode setting valid iso8601 date as nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In Swift, I have the following code...

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
let articles = try decoder.decode(Articles.self, from: data)  

class Article: Codable {

    init(_ PartitionKey : String?, RowKey : String?,  PublishedDateGmt:Date?, Title:String?) {
        self.PartitionKey = PartitionKey
        self.RowKey = RowKey
        self.PublishedDateGmt = PublishedDateGmt
        self.Title = Title
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        // include only those that you want to decode/encode
        case PartitionKey
        case PublishedDateGmt
        case Title
        case RowKey
    }


    let RowKey: String?
    let PartitionKey: String?
    let PublishedDateGmt: Date?
    let Title: String?

}
```

And this is an example of the JSON.

```
{
         "PartitionKey": “test1”,
        "RowKey": “123”,
        "PublishedDateGmt": "2019-06-29T17:27:46Z",
        "Title": “Test Title”
    }
```

Everything except PublishedDateGmt serializes.  I do not get any errors serializing it except it gives me nil.

I've even tried the code below but the date conversion fails. (In the examples below, I do get conversion failures instead of nil being the final result of the property in the Article object).

```
// let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        //dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"//2019-06-29T17:27:46Z
            //decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)
```

Everything serializes properly except for the PublishedDateGmt date field which gets serialized as nil.

An example of a date here from the json data returned is:2019-06-29T17:27:46Z

This should be a valid iso8601 date, right?

Everything else is converting properly into the Article object and the coding keys are set up correctly.

Comment: Your code works fine for me with your custom date formatter

Comment: You mean using the custom one I wrote and not relying on iso8601?  For me, when I use my custom date formatter I get a conversion error rather than just getting nil being set in the property..

Comment: What is the code you are using?

Comment: The code in your question with some minor adjustments to make it work in my playground. And yes, the formatter you configured.

Comment: Could you provide your working code?

Comment: This code used to work, and now no longer works.  I have no idea what changed because nothing did and it works fine for you...Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I discovered it is an issue with the XCode debugger.  I don't know why.  See my answer below...

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug, as far as I can tell, in the XCode debugger.  There is nothing wrong with my code.

Using the quick watch / locals window the value for PublishedDateGmt was always nil which was driving me crazy trying to debug it.

However, if you print the value out, you see that value is actually there.

See screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If anyone has any other explanation I'd like to know...