# Date issue Xcode 11, 11.1 on Mojave - debugger contradiction

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode11, xcode11.1

I'm having an issue while working with dates in Xcode11 and even on Xcode11.1. The debugger (somehow) contradicts itself.

[image]

You see, when I print the details for selectedRanges (which is a list of DateRanges with two properties:)

```
    struct DateRange: Equatable {
        var start: Date
        var end: Date?
    }
```

it shows me the correct values stored, but when I do something like this:

```
 let a = selectedRanges.filter({
        guard $0.isComplete() == true else { return false }
        guard !date.isBetween($0.start, and: $0.end!) else { return false }
        guard let firstSelectedRange = selectedRanges.first, firstSelectedRange.isComplete() == false else { return false }
       *guard firstSelectedRange.start > $0.start && date < $0.start else { return false }

        return true
    })
```

and print `firstSelecteRange.end` I get an optional value out of no were, and when tested with `!= nil` it returns a value and when tested with `.isComplete()` returns another one (isComplete method is in the image).

All prints have been done on the *line from the code.

Weirdly enough, in the debugger console I get nil sometimes on ranges that are not. 
[image]

My question is: is this an issue on Xcode, or do I miss something?

// EDIT 1: Added logs for p command:
[image]

Comment: What happens if you use `p` instead of `po` ?

Comment: updated post with a screen. basically, the same :(

Comment: See https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-11546

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58108824/instantiated-optional-variable-shows-as-nil-in-xcode-debugger

Comment: @matt thank you, this issue made me lose a valuable day :))

Comment: So can we close as duplicate? I don’t want to do that unless it’s the same bug.

Comment: @matt, yes please.