# DateFormatter/ISO8601DateFormatter can not get date from string

Tags: swift, iso8601

How to use ISO8601DateFormatter to convert a String to Date?

```
let iSO8601DateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
let string = iSO8601DateFormatter.string(from: Date()) //2019-12-04T08:23:27Z
let date = iSO8601DateFormatter.date(from: string)  //nil ?
```

The code above run in iPhone8 simulator with Xcode 11.2.1, I get nil.

But it works in the Playground of same Xcode.

Can any one help me to point what's wrong about my doing?

Answer (score 2):

It seems a bug in Xcode11 and swift 5. The date actually is not nil, but in debug, it is showed as nil.

```
let date = Date()
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
formatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime]
let dateString = formatter.string(from: date)
if let myDate = formatter.date(from: dateString){
      print(myDate) //2019-12-08 02:22:26 +0000
}
```

You can see more about the bug at this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58108824/instantiated-optional-variable-shows-as-nil-in-xcode-debugger)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify iSO8601 date formate to the NSDateFormatter to get Date:

```
  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssZ"
  let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
  print(date) //2019-12-04 12:46:00 +0000
```

You can check types of date formats at [here.](https://nsdateformatter.com/)

I hope this may be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I also test the DateFormatter: ```let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                let string = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
                let date = dateFormatter.date(from: string)``` and the date still is nil in the simulator, but works in the Playground.

Comment: @Jungenyan I check your code. It is working in my simulator. Check with an iOS device. There is no problem in your code.

Comment: I've checked my code again in the simulator and my iPhone7, the date still is nil.