# Swift DateFormatter not working on project but working in playground?

Tags: swift, xcode, date, dateformatter

I have this code in my project:

```
class ShippingDay: EVObject, Mappable {
    var periods: [String]?
    var date: Date?

    required init(map: Mapper) throws {
        self.periods = map.optionalFrom("periods")
        if let dateStr:String = map.optionalFrom("date") {
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
            //formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
            //formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
            self.date = formatter.date(from: dateStr)
        }
    }
```

here is the theoretical proof in playground that this should work:

[image]

But this is what I get:

[image]

Can some enlightened soul please explain me what the hell is happening here??
Why my self.date is always nil?
I tried without the comments and the result is the same... nil

UPDATED evidence:

[image]

Comment: set locale to formatter

    formater.locale =  Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

Comment: I did... same result

Comment: I tried setting locale, calendar and timezone... I always get nil and they work fine on playground

Comment: what is the format of your dateStr? i mean yyyy-MM-dd type

Comment: yyyy/MM/dd and you can see it's value is "2020/03/26"

Comment: I'm going nuts here... it doesn't make any sense... my mac is near to flying out of the window...

Comment: Consider that in a few countries daylight saving time changes on 2020/03/27 at midnight, so there is no date between `0:00:00` and `0:59:59`

Comment: its giving me nil for the entire array going from 2020/03/20 to 2020/03/30

Comment: I tried your code in my Xcode ,it works, May be something in your xcode,emulator,mac setting

Comment: Add `formater.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")` again and put it **before** the line to set the date format.

Comment: just tried that also... same result :'(

Comment: I think this is a xcode bug... I'm on version Version 11.3.1 (11C504)

Comment: @rickrvo you need to set the dateFormatter Locale before setting the dateFormat. Btw forget about `Mappable` and start using `Codable` protocol

Comment: @LeoDabus I tried that and it's the same result

Comment: Are you sure the date is nil? Try asking for it as NSDate. There is a bug in lldb that reports nonnil Date objects as nil. But for NSDate you get the truth. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58108824/instantiated-optional-variable-shows-as-nil-in-xcode-debugger

Comment: @matt like ->   self.date = formatter.date(from: dateStr) as NSDate   and leave the line var date:Date?  untouched?

Comment: @rickrvo make sure to set the calendar as well if you don't provide the time on your string. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32408916/2303865

Comment: @rickrvo Does it fail only with this specific date?

Comment: fails with all dates

Comment: Again just forget about Mappable

Comment: I'll update my question in a sec with the print for locale, calendar and timezone set

Comment: Try it without Mappable. Don't waste your time with it

Comment: yeah I know it's an old  and huge project I haven't had the time to update it the mappable thing... but there are other objects that do parse date correctly

Comment: @matt you sir saved my sanity! changing the type to NSDate did the trick! not just lldb that leaves it nil, it really leaves the Date object nil

Comment: As the dupe answer points out, the problem is not the `DateFormatter` or `Date`, but a debugger bug that reports `nil` when it’s not. Don’t use `NSDate` because of some debugger idiosyncrasy.

Comment: @Rob it´s not just the debugger. I think... elsewhere in the code I see nill in other Date properties parsed from this object