# Convert string to Date with short format

Tags: swift, xcode, date, time

I am having the user pick a date and time and saving that as a string I display in a text field, like so:

```
@objc func dealDateSelected(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let date = DateFormatter()
    date.dateStyle = .short
    date.timeStyle = .short
    date.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    date.locale = Locale.current

    limitedTimeTextField.text = date.string(from: sender.date)
}
```

Then I am attempting to convert that text field back to a date object later, but I cannot get it to work. The format looks like this: "6/7/20, 10:10 PM". All of the things I've seen to convert date are in a different format than what I'm using. I saw something about kCFDateFormatterShortStyle but I cannot find where to access it.

When I try this

```
//Check Time
var dateEnding: Date?
if(limitedTimeSwitch.isOn) {
    if let dateChosen = limitedTimeTextField.text {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        formatter.locale = Locale.current
        formatter.dateStyle = .short
        formatter.timeStyle = .short

        dateEnding = formatter.date(from: dateChosen)
    }
}
```

I only get nil back. I've also tried using

```
dateEnding = ISO8601DateFormatter().date(from: dateChosen)
```

but that also returns nil. My string is coming through properly as "6/7/20, 10:10 PM", in that format.

What format do I need to use to get it converted back into a date? I thought it would be simple since all I'm doing is converting date to string, then back again, but it's causing so much trouble.

[image: Showing off the nil value of conversion]

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem – I can successfully convert a date to a `String` and then back to a `Date` with the same date formatters as you. Are you sure the line `dateEnding = formatter.date(from: dateChosen)` is executing? Maybe it's not going into one of those two `if` statements.

Comment: @Tyler I'm sure. I added a photo showing the nil value, and the code going through the if statement. I thought it should work this way, too. But it just fails for me..

Comment: @ATCraiger what happens if you use a hardcoded format `date.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"` to convert to string and back to date, does it work?

Comment: How bizarre. This seems to be a problem with the debugger or something, as I can get it to show `dateEnding` as being nil, but the code execution proves that it's _not_ actually nil. See [this screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/Z07DV7e.png) that shows it going into the `else` block when checking if `dateEnding` is nil.

Comment: @Claudio with the hard coded format, it still come out as nil.

Comment: @ATCraiger I suggest you try adding the `if-else` statement like I did in my above comment to see if `dateEnding` is actually nil or if the debugger is lying to you (like it did to me).

Comment: @Tyler I did, and it went to the not nil section. What in the world. I kept going through the debugger into a function where I passed that date and it was nil all the way through. I guess I'll keep going, and try to pass it onto my web server and see if it is nil there.

Comment: Yep, looks like this might already be a known issue with Xcode 11: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58108824/instantiated-optional-variable-shows-as-nil-in-xcode-debugger

Comment: @Tyler Thanks for pointing that out. Now if only I could get back the last few hours of my life..