# Swift DateTime Formatter returning nil with matching format

Tags: swift

When parsing an input datetime string with the matching format, I am still getting nil back from DateFormatter in swift.

Input string (copied at runtime from variable) and confirmed that is the string running the call with Postman.

`"2020-06-30T14:41:33.9"`

Parsing method

```
static func FormatDateTimeString(dateTimeString: String) -> String {
    let inputDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    inputDateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.s"
    let date = inputDateFormatter.date(from:dateTimeString) //date is always nil
    
    let outputDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    outputDateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy HH:mm"
    
    return outputDateFormatter.string(from: date!)
}
```

I have also tried `"YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss.s"` and `"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss"` but none seem to work.

EDIT: Trying the format suggested below I am still getting nil.

[image]

EDIT: As Suggested from the comments I am still getting nil. Format below is: `inputDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S"`

[image]

EDIT: Still getting null using the following config

[image]

Comment: The format does not match. Year is `yyyy`, day is `dd`, the `T` must be wrapped in single quotes, hour is `HH` and fractional seconds is `SS`

Comment: ... and you should set a POSIX locale when parsing a fixed-format date string, compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/40692378/1187415.

Comment: `"en_US_POSIX"` not `"en_GB_POSIX"`

Comment: I've tried these suggestions and am still getting nil... Am I being stupid and missing something here? I had copied and pasted some of the formats, obviously they are off. It's a DateTime.UtcNow from dotnet over a web call that I am trying to parse.

Comment: Your dateFormat is wrong the correct format is `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S"`

Comment: And make sure your dateString is current timezone when parsing otherwise set the timezone to UTC

Comment: You should set the `locale` before setting the `dateFormat`. Again it should be `"en_US_POSIX"` not `"en_GB_POSIX"`

Comment: @LeoDabus I am in the UK so I thought en_GB would have been the right way to go. I tried with en_US and it is still nil. I have also moved that to the line above setting the format and I am still getting nil.

Comment: It doesn't matter. en_US_POSIX is a special locale that does not reflect the user device locale and settings. So the dateFormat wont be affected. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1480/_index.html

Comment: **if you're working with fixed-format dates, you should first set the locale of the date formatter to something appropriate for your fixed format. In most cases the best locale to choose is "en_US_POSIX", a locale that's specifically designed to yield US English results regardless of both user and system preferences. "en_US_POSIX" is also invariant in time (if the US, at some point in the future, changes the way it formats dates, "en_US" will change to reflect the new behaviour, but "en_US_POSIX" will not), and between machines ("en_US_POSIX" works the same on iOS as it does on OS X)**

Comment: try printing the date result

Comment: I'm not sure who is downvoting this question... but @LeoDabus when I print that date it has an output?!.... why is it nil according to the debugger but it has a value?

Comment: That’s a bug in Xcode: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58108824/1187415

Comment: Not related to your question but what is the purpose of your string format that you are trying to return? If you intent is to display the time the the user you should use dateStyle and timeStyle to display it in local time and localized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this format:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S"
```

## Demo

```
let dateTimeString = "2020-06-30T14:41:33.9"

let inputDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
inputDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S"
let date = inputDateFormatter.date(from: dateTimeString) // "Jun 30, 2020 at 2:41 PM"
```

Comment: And you need to set the locale to "en_US_POSIX"

Comment: I've tried this above, and as you can see it is still nill (see edited image etc)

Comment: Answers are more helpful (to the author of the question and to future readers of this thread) if they *explain* the problem and the solution, instead of posting code only.