# I'm trying to convert a string date into a Date but it keeps returning nil even after setting dateFormat

Tags: swift, date

The date i'm retrieving from `let date = message.creationTs` is in the format `creationTs: "2021-05-17 12:05:59"`

I set my dateFormat as `dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`

However `let sentDate = dateFormatter.date(from: date)` returns nil.. any ideas?

[image]

Comment: If I run your code, I get the desired output. Can you post your full code (snippet) where this happens? Also, check if `message.creationTs` really is in the correct and expected format.

Comment: @MartinFink thanks for reaching out. i included a screenshot to show u my debugging. I can also post the code itself if that helps.

Comment: How do you check it is nil? Maybe this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58108824/instantiated-optional-variable-shows-as-nil-in-xcode-debugger

Comment: @JoakimDanielson when i hover over sentDate it shows nil.. also when i insert it into a call ill get a runtime error that it's nil

Comment: If you copy the relevant code to a playground is it reproducible? If yes then please post that code as text in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the timezone like

```
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
```

if still getting a nil value try setting all these:

```
formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

Comment: To set the time zone you need to know what time zone the server uses, you can’t just set any random time zone.

Comment: that is logically true. I too faced this issue some time ago and this solution worked. if it's just to parse the date having a default timezone and/or locale will let you parse without returning nil

Comment: It will not solve anything unless you know what time zone the original date uses.